# Wordpress Advanced Custom Field - Field Not Displaying

Tags: wordpress

I am building an artist directory page which displays all the artist pages as thumbnails with captions.
I would then like it so that when you click on one of the thumbnails it takes you to that page and shows the various fields ACF.
However, it only shows the title and I cannot get it to display the bio field at all!

```
<h1><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h1>
<div id="artist-bio">
<?php the_field('artist_bio'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, it's a good practice to check if your fields have been set in the first place. You can test like this:

```
if (get_field('artist_bio') {
    the_field('artist_bio');
} else {
    echo "Artist bio has not been set";
}
```

If it's claiming that it hasn't been set, yet you're sure it is, then there's probably an issue with the loop. Are you inside the default loop, or are you running a custom query? In the latter case you would need to modify your command like so: `the_field('artist_bio', $post->ID)`.

Comment: Thanks. I have a template for an artist's page so I want it to return the field from the current artist/page. I tried what you suggested but still does not show.

Comment: Did you enter any data in your 'artist_bio' field for this page? Is is outputting "Artist bio has not been set"?